# What are the limits on networking with Windows IOT

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

I've been trying to do some fundamental networking 'stuff' with Windows IOT (Oct build) with not a lot of success. I was able to do a simple UDP broadcast (using Datagram Socket) and create a simple TCP client (using SocketAsyncEventArgs).

However I was unable to find a way to listen for a UDP broadcast. I found a couple Windows 8 phone-style examples and other older style techniques and didn't find anything that worked.

Same with creating a simple TCP server. Tried some of the popular SocketAsyncEventArgs implementations around and could never get anything to work.

I'm more than willing to believe I'm incompetent...happens all the time! But the available libraries for IOT look more 'phone-y' than 'Windows 10-y' and I'm wondering if there's just a lot of phone-style security limitations. For example I don't think Windows phone could receive a UDP broadcast.

Is it just too early? Am I missing something significant? Am I just better off putting MONO on a linux distro because they seem much farther along? Has anyone been able to do all these basic networking tasks? Or am I really just incompetent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to do some Bluetooth sockets for serial transfer and http get, post, update and delete.   Note that Capabilities are critical in UWP apps. There are three with IoT Core. One is default and the other three have to be added

- Internet Client  (In by default)
- Internet Client and Server
- Private Networks Client and Server (You won't be able to do anything locally without this).

There is also capabilities such as Bluetooth.

Edit the Package.Manifest file and choose the Capabilities tab

Hope this helps

PS You will run into problems running a service as a Background Task.

Comment: Thanks...yeah I think part of the problem was my Package.Manifest settings. Once I set those it worked better. I was able to create a TCP Client, a TCP Server, a UDP Broadcaster and a UDP Listener using the SocketAsyncEventArgs style. A little clumsy, a little 2009, but it works ok.